# docker: 'network' is not a docker command

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker

I have recently installed docker in aws ec2 instance by using the command

```
$ yum install docker
```

But when I try to run `$ docker network --help` it says

```
docker: 'network' is not a docker command.
```

Please let me know what is the issue here.

Here is the output of docker version

```
Client version: 1.7.1
Client API version: 1.19
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 786b29d/1.7.1
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.7.1
Server API version: 1.19
Go version (server): go1.4.2
Git commit (server): 786b29d/1.7.1
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docker engine release notes](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#190-2015-11-03) I see in docker 1.9

> `docker network` exits experimental and is part of standard release (#16645)

so docker 1.7.1 seems a bit too old to support `docker network`.
[Amazon Linux AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/) has only [docker 1.7.1 in its latest release 2015.09](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2015.09-release-notes/), which means it you need and try to [install the latest docker yourself](http://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/).

Comment: So please tell me your suggestion to interact with docker networking.

Comment: As mentioned in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html#install_docker, you need to install the latest docker (http://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/)

Comment: @user3836226 However, the latest Amazon Linux (https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2015.09-release-notes/) only include 1.7.1. See slide 23 of http://www.slideshare.net/Docker/experiences-with-aws-immutable-deploys-and-job-processing

Comment: Ok then i will try to install latest version of docker in another EC2 instance with ubuntu installed. Thank you!!